# What will be the limit points of the set, $S=\{(-1)^{n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Since the set, S, turns out to be a finite set consisting of just two elements, i.e. $\{-1,1\}$, therefore there should be no limit points to the set.

But the solution given in the book is, the set S has two limit points $-1$ and $1$.

Which solution is correct?

Comment: What is your definition of a limit point?

Comment: A limit point of a set, S is a point, x such that every neighbourhood of x (open sets containing x) contains a member of S other than x.

Comment: It depends on what topological space you are working in (*and in particular what topology you are using*), and how you define a limit point.  Under the usual topology of $\Bbb R$ and your definition of limit points that you gave in your comment just now, [any finite set has no limit points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280993/prove-that-if-s-is-a-finite-set-then-s-has-no-limit-points?rq=1).

Comment: In your definition of a limit point, the set $S$ has no limit points, because the ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ around $1$ or $-1$ does not contain the other point. One can define (as is done at my school) a limit point as one in which any neighbourhood of the point contains a point in $S$, and under this definition both $1$ and $-1$ are limit points of $S$.

Comment: Your book is probably talking about the *sequence* $\{(-1)^n\}$, not the set $S$.

Comment: A related but different question, considering the sequence $(S)_n$ where $S_n=(-1)^n$, both $1$ and $-1$ are limits of some subsequence, and indeed only $1$ and $-1$ are possible subsequence limits.

Comment: @Jack makes a good point. The question may be asking for the set of limits of subsequences of the sequence $\{(-1)^n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$, which is $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: @Jack can you elaborate your point a little bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation $\{(-1)^n\mid {n\in{\bf N}}\}$, understood as a *set*, is the same as $\{-1,1\}$, which has no limit point.

However, in some context, $\{(-1)^n\mid {n\in{\bf N}}\}$ is used as a (bad) notation for the real sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with $a_n:=(-1)^n$. In this case,

> $x$ is a "limit point" of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

means

> $x$ is the limit of some convergent subsequence of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

Note that both $1$ and $-1$ are limits of some subsequences of the sequence $((-1)^n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

For more general discussions, see the Wikipedia article on [Limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).

Comment: But still the neighbourhood of say 1 does not contain any of the point of the set except for 1.

Comment: @AjayChoudhary The idea here is that the definition of limit point for a *set* and limit point for a *sequence* are different - in particular, $\{-1,1\}$ has no limit points, but the sequence $((-1)^n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does have a limit point, because "limit point" means two different things in either situation.